# Where does databricks delta stores it's metadata?

Tags: pyspark, metadata, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Hive stores its metadata I'm external database like SQL server. Similar to that where does the databricks delta stores its metadata Information?

Answer (score 4):

Databricks Delta stores its metadata on the file system. They are just files in either json (for each transaction) or parquet format (for a snapshot of the table metadata at some version).

Comment: The metadata is just stored with the data files. You can see there is a directory called "_delta_log" in your Delta table directory. If you are using S3 to store the data,  the metadata is on S3 as well. However, the metadata cannot be stored in a database because that's not scale.

Comment: Got it... Understood